# Strange overfull \hbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

I'm having a strange issue with LaTeX where I'm getting overfull `\hbox` warnings for seemingly no reason (of course there is one, I just can't figure it out). I'm hoping someone can illuminate the problem for me and provide a solution. I've removed all personal information from my CV and the problem remains still, here's the problematic LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{resume} 
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.6in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry}
\name{John Doe}
\address{John.Doe@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The warning I get is "Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--5" but I can't see why exactly. Please advise!
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  `resume` is not a standard class, so we can't really help you.  Where did you get the class?

Comment: it's a 12 year old file that does `\renewcommand{\document}{` which was probably a bad idea then and almost certainly a bad idea with current latex. However replace `\break` by `\par`in `\printname` fixes the overfull box:  `\def \printname {%
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\par%\break
  \endgroup
}
`